# Show that $x^2 + xy^2+ xyz^2\geq 4xyz-4 $ for positive real $x,y,z$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $x$,$y$ and $z$ are three positive real numbers.Show that $x^2 + xy^2+ xyz^2\geq 4xyz-4 $.
I have tried to attack the problem by order relationship $x \geq y \geq z$ and then converting them into single variable , AM-GM on $x^2 + xy^2+ xyz^2$  and $x^2 + xy^2+ xyz^2 + 4 $ but nothing is taking me anywhere near to the solution. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$x^2+xy^2+xyz^2+4=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{xy^2}{8}+\dots+\frac{xy^2}{8}+\frac{xyz^2}{16}+\dots+\frac{xyz^2}{16}+1+1+1+1$$

You can apply AM-GM.

**Side Note**

Note your attempt to prove the inequality by assuming $x \ge y \ge z$ is wrong as $x,y,z$ are not interchangeable.

Comment: Brilliant. But I am wondering how on earth  can this be thought of? Can you please be kind enough to share how you hit upon the idea to write it in this way? And why it is wrong to assume $x \geq y \geq z $?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rugi The trick is to set $x=y=z$. The equality holds when $x=y=z=2$. Try to make $x^2$ and $xy^2$ equal when $x=y=2$, by dividing them with constants. Note that it is wrong to assume that $x \ge y \ge z$, because while it might be true for $x \ge y \ge z$, it may not be true for $x \ge z \ge y$. To assume that $x \ge y \ge z$ without loss of generality, one must assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for improving my knowledge and teaching a very important thing.

Comment: @rugi  However, note that my trick is not always applicable-generally, the inequality holds when $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers(because they are nicer then when they are irrational). But, there are always problems like this: Find the minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^3$ when $x+y+z=3$. The answer to this is a very complex looking irrational. In these cases, just stare at the problem until you think of when the inequality holds.

Comment: The minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^3$ when $x+y+z=3$, is actually $\frac{541-37 \sqrt{37}}{108}$

Comment: Thanks. Knowledge increased and idea sharpened.This is a bonus :)